# Python script timeouts while uploading to an ftp server

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm creating an csv file and uploading it to a ftp server.
So the upload includes paths of multiple companies on that ftp server.

like :

**COMANY1/FOO/BAR**

But for some companies at the end I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exporter.py", line 117, in <module>
    Exporter().run()
  File "exporter.py", line 115, in run
    self.upload(file, vendor['ftp_path'], filename)
  File "exporter.py", line 78, in upload
    sftp.chdir(dir)
  File "/home/johndoe/exports/daily/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 580, in chdir
    if not stat.S_ISDIR(self.stat(path).st_mode):
  File "/home/johndoe/exports/daily/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 413, in stat
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)
  File "/home/johndoe/exports/daily/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 730, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/home/johndoe/exports/daily/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 781, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/home/johndoe/exports/daily/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 807, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
IOError: [Errno 2] The requested file does not exist
```

I think the stack trace refers to the ftp path, that it doesn't exists (but It does exist).

But when I try to run that script on those exact same paths alone (that are causing the problem) it passes?

So, its not a logical error, and those ftp paths do exist - but can it be due to some timeout occurring?

Thanks,
Tom

---

**Update:**

I call the method like this:

```
self.upload(file, vendor['ftp_path'], filename)
```

And the actual method that does the uploading:

```
def upload(self, buffer, ftp_dir, filename):

    for dir in ftp_dir.split('/'):
        if dir == '':
            continue
        sftp.chdir(dir)

    with sftp.open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(buffer)
    f.close()

    sftp.close()
```

Comment: can you show the code? and how are you passing the websites ?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: This is indeed your lib's way of telling you that it can't find any file: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/sftp_client.py#L859

Comment: And in this case, the "file" is most likely a directory, because the error starts when you try to change directory with `sftp.chdir`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think also, but the problem is that when I run my script in a cron it returns that stacktrace - that a couple of ftp paths dont egzist! But when I try to run the script only on those ftp paths (not all - there are about 25 of them on the same server) it works? So the direcories are there - thats's whats puzzling me :)